# Calling jquery colorbox from domready window.add event

Tags: jquery, colorbox, domready

I have the following code:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){var myBox = new BoxMenu({items: [['Card Info', 'item_1.png',function(){ window.location = "card"; }],]});});
```

This code creates a box menu item and when clicked it opens the window "card". No problem.

But I don't want the user to move away from the main window so instead I decided to use jQuery colorbox.

I need to know how to call the iframe class which calls the colorbox script to open FROM this page.

normally (in one page only) it is done by:

```
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict(); 
    (function($) { 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
        $("#click").click(function(){ 
            $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
            return false;
        });
    });
          })(jQuery); 
</script>

then the HTML 

<p><a class='iframe' href="reach.html">Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a></p>
```

But in this case the box menu IS the link itself. Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

in the window.event the colorbox is called the following way:

```
['Card Info', 'item1.png',function call_cbox(){jQuery().colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", opacity:0.8, iframe:true, href:"reach.html"});}],
```

thank you and hope this can help someone too.